# Is there a onrerender event for jsf?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have an ***a4j:outputPanel***. I rerender that with a click on another place in the page and I want to fire an action when that `outputPanel` is rerendered.

Is there a onrerender event or something? I´ve tried and I´ve searched but I can´t do what I want.
I know I could use oncomplete event where I fire the rerender operation but that´s 
what I don´t want to do.

Anyway, do you have any ideas? I do not need the exact solution, just ideas can help me to find the way to do this.

EDIT: Sorry for the mistake, the action i want to fire is a js action.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing

```
<f:event listener="#{myBean.myAction}" type="preRenderComponent"></f:event>
```

Inside your `outputPanel`...

```
public void myAction(ComponentSystemEvent componentSystemEvent) {  
   //some code goes here...
}
```

---

If you want to call js code from your managed bean method you can use [Primefaces - RequestContext](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/requestContext.jsf)

```
public void myAction(ComponentSystemEvent componentSystemEvent) {  
    RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
    requestContext.execute("alert('wow')");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; and i´m sorry, but i can´t use it because i want to fire a js action, not a bean action.

Comment: Just let the bean action trigger a JS action?

Comment: @SebastiánAguerre , so why not use oncomplete and inside it jsut check that the `outputPanel` is really rendered `$('#panelId').length > 0`

Comment: Thank you, finally the team has decided that i will just do it on the oncomplete event of the panel that does the rerender.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the action rerenders component then why not add it in the action itself . You can also use method suggested by Daniel and add JavaScript call from your Java method . Icefaces comes with a JavaScript context class , I am sure richfaces will have something  similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `onbeforedomupdate` of the `<a4j:ajax/>` component

```
<a4j:outputPanel>
   <a4j:ajax onbeforedomupdate="yourJs();"/>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you, finally the team has decided that i will just do it on the oncomplete event of the panel that does the rerender.
But i will try this and use it the next time if works.